# Upload .txt as one cell for further editing

Tags: r, text-mining

My question: how to upload a .txt to appear as one cell

I need to prepare my data first and want to do that in R. So I want to upload the .txt file I have to R so that it is in the shape of a single cell first. Through that I can do some clean-up first, before splitting it to rows and cells.

Let's say I have:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,`

`sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.`

`At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.`

I would like to load that to be all in one single cell to do some conversion first. With `readr` or any other import tool it will always be split into rows according to the line breaks.

Comment: Please provide some sample data, what you have tried, and what your expected output is.

Comment: @Paul Thx, I have added some more info.

Comment: does the base package `scan` do what you want? It imports a file as a vector.

Comment: Scan doesn't work as I have all kinds of special characters "\" and "_" which scan dosn't like

Answer (score 0):

I found that `readtext` package is what I was looking for.

`install.packages("readtext")
library(readtext)
d <- readtext("~.txt", text_field = "texts")`

This will load the entire text file in one cell, a second cell will contain
information about the file name.

More info: 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readtext/vignettes/readtext_vignette.html